# JcheckBox in Jtable

Tags: swing

I am having Check box in my Jtable.Check box displayed in center of column.My problem is when i click on check box it moves to left of that column and comes to center functionality wise works fine.Can any one tell How to stop the movement of checkbox

Thanks Ganesh

Comment: Some code would help. And a screenshot if possible...

Answer (score 2):

Renderer and editor are handled separately. So when you click the cell, it will display the editor component instead of the renderer component displayed previously. Sounds like you have centered the JCheckBox used as renderer, but not the JCheckBox used as editor. Center the editor the same way you have centered the renderer.

This is the best answer I can give you without further details.